# Difference between validation result in fit_generator and predict_generator

Tags: keras

I am having an issue which I cannot understand.

For training, I am using fit_generator as below and the validation data returns f1 score around 0.8

```
validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory=val_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        classes=["0", "1"],
        class_mode="categorical")
myModel.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=int(nbr_train_samples / batch_size) + (nbr_train_samples % batch_size > 0),
        epochs=nbr_epochs,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=int(nbr_validation_samples / batch_size) + (nbr_validation_samples % batch_size > 0))
```

Then I use predict_generator on the same set of data using in validation data above. The only difference is that I merge two sub-folders under valid_data_dir to a single folder in test_data_dir and call the below methods

```
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory= test_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=False,
        classes=None,
        class_mode=None)
predictions = myModel.predict_generator(test_generator, int(nbr_test_samples / batch_size) + (nbr_test_samples % batch_size > 0), verbose=1)
```

Then, I calculate f1 from predictions and the result is very low.

Comment: Welcome to SO. (1) Are you sure this is a coding issue? And not just that you have overfit your data? (2) You may well need to provide a [mcve] with some data that helps others reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think that it is the overfit issue. It is because I used exactly the same set of data for validation in fit_generator and in predict_generator. WIth the same model, the same set of data, but two different results, I cannot understand.

Comment: I actually found some similar questions about this issue. However, in these questions, people often made a mistake by forgetting to set shuffle = False, and hence because the images are shuffled, the results cannot be matched. In my case, I did the correct setting.

Comment: I think that I've found the issue. It was in the way I calculated f1 score for validation. It is not correct when using with 'categorical' mode. Need to use 'binary' mode instead.